# Which numerical method can I use to solve this system of hyperbolic PDEs?

Tags: finite-difference, reference-request, stability, hyperbolic-pde, wave-propagation

**Backround**

The mathematical model I am trying to numerically solve models wave propagation inside a cylinder with specific material properties suited for dynamic loading. The cylinder's upper base is under the impact pressure of a rigid body, while the lower base is fixed (as presented in the picture below):

[image: Impact]

**Model**

In its dimensionless form, the model consists of the following three hyperbolic PDEs in which the given functions depend on time, as well as the radial and longitudinal coordinates:

$$ {\partial ^2 u \over \partial r^2} + {1 \over r}{\partial u \over \partial r} +{\partial ^2 u \over \partial z^2}-f={1\over c^2}{\partial ^2 u \over \partial t^2} \tag 1$$

$$ {\partial ^2 f \over \partial r^2} + {1 \over r}{\partial f \over \partial r} +{\partial ^2 f \over \partial z^2}={\partial ^2 f \over \partial t^2} \tag 2$$

$$ {\partial ^2 v \over \partial r^2} + {1 \over r}{\partial v \over \partial r} -{1\over r^2}v+c^2{\partial ^2 v \over \partial z^2}+\big(1-c^2\big){\partial ^3 u \over \partial r\partial z^2}={\partial ^2 v \over \partial t^2} \tag 3$$

where $u$ is the longitudinal displacement, $f$ is a function defined by $(1)$, $v$ is the longitudinal rate of change of radial displacement and $c$ is a material constant.

The initial conditions of these functions are zero:

$$u(r,z,0)=f(r,z,0)=v(r,z,0)=0 \tag 4$$
$${\partial u \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0}={\partial f \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0}={\partial v \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0}=0 \tag 5$$

The cylinder is fixed at its bottom base, so I have the following zero boundary conditions at $z = 1$:

$$u(r,1,t)=f(r,1,t)=v(r,1,t)=0 \tag 6$$

Also, I have the following zero boundary conditions at the cylinder's axis:

$$ {\partial u \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=0}={\partial f \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=0} = v(0,z,t) = 0 \tag 7$$

Note that instead of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ which contain singularities, the following two equations can be used at the cylinder's axis:

$$ 2{\partial ^2 u \over \partial r^2} + {\partial ^2 u \over \partial z^2}-f={1\over c^2}{\partial ^2 u \over \partial t^2} \tag 8$$

$$ 2{\partial ^2 f \over \partial r^2} + {\partial ^2 f \over \partial z^2}={\partial ^2 f \over \partial t^2} \tag 9$$

The boundary conditions of the cylinder's curved surface are the following:

$${\partial u \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=r_{max}}=-v(r_{max},z,t) \tag {10}$$
$${\partial v \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=r_{max}}={2c^2-1 \over 2\big(c^2-1\big)}f(r_{max},z,t) \tag {11}$$

$$ {\partial f \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=r_{max}}= {c^2-1 \over c^2} \Bigg(
{\partial ^2 v \over \partial r^2}\Bigg |_{r=r_{max}} + {1 \over r}{2c^2-1 \over 2\big(c^2-1\big)}f(r_{max},z,t) -{1\over r^2}v(r_{max},z,t)-{\partial ^2 v \over \partial z^2}\Bigg |_{r=r_{max}} \Bigg) \tag {12}$$

For the upper base of the cylinder, I have the following two zero boundary conditions:

$$ {\partial f \over \partial z} \Bigg |_{z=0} = v(r,0,t)=0 \tag {13}$$

As for the boundary condition for the longitudinal displacement, it satisfies the position continuity condition:

$$u(r,0,t) = p(t) \tag {14}$$

where $p(t)$ is the position of the rigid body. This function satisfies the following equation (derived by using Newtons and Hooks laws):

$${d^2 p \over dt^2}=-m {\partial u \over \partial z} \Bigg |_{z=0}\tag {15}$$
where $m$ represents the elastic body and rigid body mass ratio. The following two initial conditions are known:

$$p(0)=0 \tag {16}$$
$${dp\over dt}\Bigg |_{t=0}=V_0 \tag {17}$$

where the initial rigid body velocity is under the restriction $V_0<1$. Also, at $z=0$, I have the following boundary conditions:

$${\partial u \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{z=0}=0 \tag {18}$$
$${\partial^2 u \over \partial z^2} \Bigg |_{z=0}={c^2 \over c^2-1}f(r,0,t) \tag {19}$$

The model I wrote down has the following problems. The first is the corner singularity problem at the corner $(r=r_{max},z=0)$. Namely, the condition $(11)$ and $v(r_{max},0,t)=0$ can not be satisfied both at the same time. For my simulation, I chose the condition $v(r_{max},0,t)=0$ to be satisfied. However, this is a weak singularity, meaning the solution can still be approximated numerically, but with reduced accuracy. More on this can be found in J.P. Boyd's book ["Cheybeshev and Fourier Spectral Methods"](https://depts.washington.edu/ph506/Boyd.pdf)".

The other problem is that the rigid body and the elastic body contact surfaces do not have the same velocities at the initial moment of the impact. This is why I would restrict equation $(1)$ to be solved for $z>0$ and I would calculate the longitudinal displacement at $z=0$ by solving equation $(15)$ first and then applying the condition $(14)$.

I tried to solve these equations using the finite difference method. As expected, it didn't give a stable solution. I used the center difference scheme which has the problem of numerical diffusion. Also, the solution for $v$ has a big spike near the corner $(z=0,r=r_{max})$ which throws all of the other calculations to spike at the same place out of bounds. This is shown in the pictures below.

[image: Spikes]

However, I also noticed another problem. It takes five time steps for the function $v$ to finally be non-zero at $(r, z=\Delta z)$, and six time steps for the function $f$ to be non-zero at $(r,z=0)$. I fear this is physically impossible, especially since the function $f$ needs to satisfy the compatibility condition $(19)$. At the sixth time step, the function $u$ was already non-zero at $(r, z=\{0,\  \Delta z,\ 2\Delta z,\ 3\Delta z,\ 4\Delta z,\ 5\Delta z\})$

This means that choosing a numerical method that can actually solve this problem is not trivial.

I have a good background in finite differences and basic knowledge of the spectral method. Apart from that, I don't know how to use some other popular methods such as finite elements. But I would like to study and learn any numerical method, as long as it can solve my model.

So my question is, which numerical method can I use to solve my problem? How can I compensate the corner singularity, numerical diffusion and the compatibility-delay problem I described?

A reference to literature to learn the appropriate method would also be helpful. Thank you for your time.